# How to compare two data frames with same columns but different number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas

> df1=

```
  A   B  C  D

  a1  b1 c1 1

  a2  b2 c2 2

  a3  b3 c3 4
```

> df2=

```
  A   B  C  D

  a1  b1 c1 2

  a2  b2 c2 1
```

I want to compare the value of the column 'D' in both dataframes. If both dataframes had same number of rows I would just do this.

> newDF = df1['D']-df2['D']

However there are times when the number of rows are different. I want a result Dataframe which shows a dataframe like this.

> resultDF=

```
  A   B  C  D_df1 D_df2  Diff

  a1  b1 c1  1     2       -1

  a2  b2 c2  2     1        1
```

EDIT:  if 1st row in A,B,C from df1 and df2 is same then and only then compare 1st row of column D for each dataframe. Similarly, repeat for all the row.

Comment: thanks, this prints the difference in the 'D' column .However it doesn't compare row by row as in.  if 1st row in A,B,C from df1 and df2 is same then and only then compare D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` and `df.eval`

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['A','B','C'], suffixes=['_df1','_df2']).eval('Diff=D_df1 - D_df2')

Out[314]:
    A   B   C  D_df1  D_df2  Diff
0  a1  b1  c1      1      2    -1
1  a2  b2  c2      2      1     1
```